# Use ConditionExpression to limit insert when ID doesn't exist in other table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Simple thing. While inserting data to table **A** I have a HashKey *id* and additional hash index for column *ex_id*, which is kind of a foreign key in table **B**.

When inserting a new data into table **A** I would like to create an exception whenever data is inserted with value in column *ex_id* that doesn't have a correspondent entry in table **B**.

I thought that `ConditionExpression` is the way to go, but can't make it work - probably missing something obvious. Tried to use `contains()`...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge this would not be possible at DynamoDB end because there are no relationship between the tables.

What you can do is that you can have a condition at the application level, which checks on its own and throw an exception before inserting the value in table A. (You can query table B for that "Id" if found then insert else throw exception)

Comment: That's what I did. But it sounded so logical since it's a simple get by hash. If it's not supported on DynamoDB level, it's kinda dissapointing...

Comment: yes, currently there is no support as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not natively support any kind of foreign key support, everything works on a per table basis, per key basis. DynamoDB's approach is to handle such logic at the client level. For example see the [dynamodb transactions client](https://github.com/awslabs/dynamodb-transactions). This library allows you to perform transactions across tables which either all succeed or all rollback.

For your case, I would first make a getItem request to table **B** (use consistent read) if it exists then write to table **A**.

Then I would enable streams on table **A** and write a lambda function to check if any data violations get written to the table.